# how to display the search result from the grid using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have my jquery like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#NotAllotedStudentsGrid').jtable({
        title: 'Allot to Students below',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 5,
        sorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
        selecting: true, //Enable selecting
        multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
        selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkbo.xes on first column
        actions: {
            listAction: '@Url.Action("NotAllotedStudentsList")',
            //deleteAction: '@Url.Action("DeleteStudent")',
            //updateAction: '@Url.Action("UpdateStudent")',
            //createAction: '@Url.Action("CreateStudent")'
        },
        fields: {
            UserNo: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: false
            },
            Name: {
                title: 'Name',
                width: '15%'
            },
            Batch: {
                title: 'Batch',
            },
            EmailAddress: {
                title: 'Email address',
            },
            ContactNo: {
                title: 'Contact No',
                type: 'textarea',
            }
        }
    });

    //Load student list from server
    $('#NotAllotedStudentsGrid').jtable('load'); 

     $('#SearchFor').button().click(function () {
        var SearchForValue = $("#NotAllotedStudentsList").val();
        var StudentInputTypeValue = $("#InputType").val();
        var options = {};
            options.type = "POST";
            options.url = "/Dashboard/NotAllotedStudentsList/";
            options.data = JSON.stringify({ model: { SearchFor: SearchForValue, StudentInputType:                  StudentInputTypeValue } });
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.contentType = "application/json";
            $.ajax(options);![enter image description here][1]
    });
```

i have my controller like,

```
    public ActionResult NotAllotedStudentsList(AllotQuestionSet model,int jtStartIndex = 0, int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null)
    {
        List<TutorStudentsGridModel> tutorStudentsGridModelList = new List<TutorStudentsGridModel>();
        User userDetails = _sessionHelper.Get<User>(KrackemSessionConstants.UserDetails);
        StudentResponse studentListResponse = new StudentResponse();
        int questionSetNo = Int32.Parse(_sessionHelper.Get<string>(KrackemSessionConstants.QuestionSetNo));
       if (model.SearchFor == null)
        {
            StudentRequest studentRequest = new StudentRequest
            {
                TutorUserNo = userDetails.UserNo,
                QuestionSetNo = questionSetNo
            };
             studentListResponse = _questionSetServiceHelper.GetNotAllottedStudentsByTutorNo(studentRequest);
         }
        //Get Not Allotted Students By Name
        if (model.SearchFor != null && model.StudentInputType == StudentInputType.Name)
        {
            StudentRequest studentRequest = new StudentRequest
            {
                TutorUserNo = userDetails.UserNo,
                QuestionSetNo = questionSetNo,
                InputString = model.SearchFor
            };
             studentListResponse = _questionSetServiceHelper.GetNotAllottedStudentsByName(studentRequest);
        }
               foreach (StudentContract studentDetails in studentListResponse.StudentList)
            {
                TutorStudentsGridModel tutorStudentsGridModel = MappingEngineFactory.GetMappingEngine().Map<StudentContract, TutorStudentsGridModel>(
                    studentDetails);
                tutorStudentsGridModel.Id = studentDetails.UserNo;
                tutorStudentsGridModelList.Add(tutorStudentsGridModel);
            }
        if (jtSorting != null)
            tutorStudentsGridModelList = ControllerHelper.SortList(jtSorting, tutorStudentsGridModelList);
           tutorStudentsGridModelList = jtPageSize > 0 ? tutorStudentsGridModelList.Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize).ToList() : tutorStudentsGridModelList.ToList();
           return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = tutorStudentsGridModelList, TotalRecordCount = studentListResponse.StudentList.Count() });
    }
```

Initially, the page with grid get loaded from server with the list of students with fields i.name ii.batch iii.email iv.contact_no,  after selecting "name" from dropdown and entered a name in textbox then clicking the search button for search  , the search results should display. But its displaying old grid. kindly tell me how to display the search result from the grid using jquery.

Comment: If your search click operation is sucessful then where is sucess handler? Where are results bound again to grid?

Comment: Actually iam getting the search results from server, its not displaying. But i want to handle the search result in jquery also to display it.

Comment: For that where is your JQuery ajax sucess or error handler?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp  where is this part -success(result,status,xhr)
A function to be run when the request succeeds